# Setting up JSF project with eclipseEE and maven

Tags: eclipse, maven, jsf-2, glassfish

I'm trying to get started with JSF 2.2 in Eclipse with glassfish.

Here's what I did:

1. new maven project with no archetype selected (skipped archetype selection), I configure the maven project with war as packaging
2. I change the compiler level to 1.7
3. In the project facets, I choose JavaServerFaces 2.2 Project, select glassfish as runtime, change Java to 1.7 and Dynamic Web Module to 3.1
4. I add the following dependency:

   ```
   <dependency>
       <groupId>org.glassfish</groupId>
       <artifactId>javax.faces</artifactId>
       <version>2.2.8</version>
   </dependency>
   ```
5. I create an index.xhtml file in the webapp folder:

   ```
   <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
           "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"
           >
   <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
         xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
         xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
         xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
           >

   <h:head/>
   <h:body>
       TEST
   </h:body>
   </html>
   ```
6. I run the index.xhtml on the glassfish server and go to `http://localhost:8080/JavaServerFaces/index.xhtml`
   and see TEST.
7. I create a JavaBean in the `src/main/java` folder:

   ```
   import javax.inject.Named;

   @Named
   public class TestBean {

     private String name;

     public TestBean() {
       name = "TESTNAME";
     }

     public String getName() {
       return name;
     }
     public void setName(String name) {
       this.name = name;
     }
   }
   ```
8. I access that bean in my index.xhtml

   ```
   <h:body>
        TEST 
        Welcome #{testbean.name}
   </h:body>
   ```
9. I run it on the server and get the following output:

TEST Welcome #{testbean.name}

I don't get any errors.

What did I miss or configure incorrectly? I didn't change anything in the `web.xml` or `faces-config.xml` because I read that they're optional.

Thanx a lot for help and tips!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `web.xml` you have to configure `javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet` as follows

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

The access `http://localhost:8080/JavaServerFaces/index.xhtml` it should work.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I thought web.xml was optional now.